# from package_aa import bb, what is the design reason to run everything in __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-import

For example, with the following files:

```
package_aa/
--__init__.py
--bb.py
```

It does not seem logical to run everything in _*init*_.py, when only module bb is imported:

```
from package_aa import bb
```

Are there any design reasons or special cases behind this?

Comment: If your code wasn't supposed to run when `bb` is imported, it shouldn't have been in `__init__.py`.

Comment: (See also: everyone asking "why did Python run my whole file when I only imported one function".)

Comment: `__init__.py` could very well have chosen one of several implementations of `bb`, depending on your platform or some other factor.  Also, there's the issue of `bb` perhaps wanting to see a consistent state of the package it's part of, rather than having different amounts of it loaded depending on exactly how it was imported.